# Saving Urdu tweets from tweepy in CSV file

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to save only Urdu language tweets using tweepy in python. I am using 3.6 version of python. The data in Urdu language is not saving in the file if I open the file I am only been able to see only the usernames, not tweets in Urdu. this is my code

The same code is working for the English language.

```
import re
import io
import csv
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
#from textblob import TextBlob


consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
# set access token and secret
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
# create tweepy API object to fetch tweets
api = tweepy.API(auth)




def get_tweets(query, count = 300):

    # empty list to store parsed tweets
    tweets = []
    target = io.open("newsfileurdu.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    # call twitter api to fetch tweets
    q=str(query)
    a=str(q+" اردو")
    b=str(q+" خبریں")
    c=str(q+" خبریں اردو")
    fetched_tweets = api.search(a, count = count)+ api.search(b, count = count)+ api.search(c, count = count)
    # parsing tweets one by one
    print(len(fetched_tweets))

    for tweet in fetched_tweets:

        # empty dictionary to store required params of a tweet
        parsed_tweet = {}
        # saving text of tweet
        parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text
        if "http" not in tweet.text:
            line = re.sub("[^A-Za-z]", " ", tweet.text)
            target.write(line+"\n")
    return tweets

    # creating object of TwitterClient Class
    # calling function to get tweets
tweets = get_tweets(query ="", count = 20000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **language of the desired tweets**(urdu in this case) can be extracted by passing the `lang="ur"` to the `api.search` function or use the code snippet below:

```
api.search(q=<query goes here>, lang ['ur'], tweet_mode='extended', count=<tweets_per_query>)
```

The tweepy search API specifies the "lang" parameter using **ISO 639-1 code** (so for urdu it is "ur"). So for any desired language, the tweets can be extracted by just searching in the [language code here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), and passing that code to the lang parameter.

Comment: positional argument follows keyword argument